# Java 1.8.20 Compiler error

Tags: java, guava, java-8

The following block of code compiles just fine in 1.8.11, but throws an error in 1.8.20

```
private static String calculateSyntheticOrderTypePrice(
        FluentIterable<? extends CalculatorProvider> pendingProviders )
{
    FluentIterable <? extends CalculatorProvider> mlsLegProvidersAll = pendingProviders.filter(Predicates.and(
            IS_MLS_PROVIDER, Predicates.not(IS_SYNTHETIC)));
    FluentIterable <? extends CalculatorProvider> mlsLegProvidersNewest = reduceToNewestMlsPrices(mlsLegProvidersAll);

    FluentIterable <? extends CalculatorProvider> otherLegProviderAll = pendingProviders.filter(Predicates.and(
            Predicates.not(IS_MLS_PROVIDER), Predicates.not(IS_SYNTHETIC)));

    FluentIterable <String> mlsHeadPriceTypes = mlsLegProvidersNewest.transform(TO_MLS_SPREAD_PRICE_FUN); /* MLS head: spread price */
    FluentIterable <String> orderPriceTypes = otherLegProviderAll.transform(TO_ORDER_TYPE_PRICE_FUN);         /* non-MLS orders: option spread or pairs */

    FluentIterable <String> formattedOrderHeadPriceTypes = orderPriceTypes.transform(new FormatOrderTypePriceFun(creditOrDebit(otherLegProviderAll)));
    FluentIterable <String> allFormatted =  FluentIterable.from(Iterables.concat(mlsHeadPriceTypes, formattedOrderHeadPriceTypes));

    return CalculatorValues.rollupStrings(allFormatted);
}
```

The error I get is java:not suitable method found for filter (com.google.common.base.Predicate)

Was there a change between update 8 and 20 that would affect this code?  I am using the same version of guava in both cases 17.0 (latest stable) and the only change is update version in Java.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

edit

The line showing the error is

```
FluentIterable <? extends CalculatorProvider> mlsLegProvidersAll = pendingProviders.filter(Predicates.and(
            IS_MLS_PROVIDER, Predicates.not(IS_SYNTHETIC)));
```

Comment: Can you shorten your code to the minimal piece needed to reproduce the error?

Comment: Now please post the full and exact error message.

Comment: It would be nice to have the declaration of `IS_SYNTHETIC` and `IS_MLS_PROVIDER` as well.

Comment: This looks like https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8051402

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely [JDK-8051402](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8051402) which was introduced after JDK 8u11, found in JDK 8u20 but too late to fix, and was fixed after JDK 8u20. The fix appears in the [JDK 8u40 early access](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) snapshot build b02 and in the [JDK 9 early access](https://jdk9.java.net/download/) snapshot build b27.

Here's a minimized code fragment that illustrates the problem:

```
public class X {
    static Predicate<Number> IS_SYNTHETIC = p -> false;
    static Predicate<Number> IS_MLS_PROVIDER = p -> true;

    static void calcSynth(Stream<? extends Number> providers) {
        Stream<? extends Number> all =
            providers.filter(Predicates.and(IS_MLS_PROVIDER,
                                            Predicates.not(IS_SYNTHETIC)));
    }
}

class Predicates {
    static <T> Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> p1, Predicate<? super T> p2) {
        return x -> p1.test(x) && p2.test(x);
    }

    static <T> Predicate<T> not(Predicate<T> p) {
        return x -> !p.test(x);
    }
}
```

This works on JDK 8u11's javac, fails on JDK 8u20, and works again on JDK 8u40-b02 and JDK9-b27.