# java8 Collectors.toMap() limitation?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to use java8's `Collectors.toMap` on a `Stream` of `ZipEntry`. It may not be the best idea because of possible exceptions occuring during the processing, but I guess it ought to be possible.

I am now getting a compile error (type inference engine I guess) which I don't understand.

Here's some extracted demo code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class TestMapCollector {

    private static class MyObject {
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {
        try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("test")) {
            Map<String, MyObject> result = zipFile.stream()
                    .map(ZipEntry::getName)
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> "test", f -> new MyObject()));
        }
    }
}
```

This code builds as-is, however it doesn't build if you just comment the `.map(ZipEntry::getName)` line. As if the `toMap` collector could work if the input is a stream of `String` but not if the input is a stream of `ZipEntry`?

For reference, here is the beginning of the build error, it's quite obscure:

```
no suitable method found for collect(Collector<Object,CAP#1,Map<String,MyObject>>)
    method Stream.<R#1>collect(Supplier<R#1>,BiConsumer<R#1,? super CAP#2>,BiConsumer<R#1,R#1>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R#1
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Stream.<R#2,A>collect(Collector<? super CAP#2,A,R#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R#2,A,CAP#3,T#2,K,U
        (argument mismatch; Collector<CAP#2,CAP#4,Map<Object,Object>> cannot be converted to Collector<? super CAP#2,CAP#4,Map<Object,Object>>))
  where R#1,T#1,R#2,A,T#2,K,U are type-variables:
    R#1 extends Object declared in method <R#1>collect(Supplier<R#1>,BiConsumer<R#1,? super T#1>,BiConsumer<R#1,R#1>)
    T#1 extends Object declared in interface Stream
    R#2 extends Object declared in method <R#2,A>collect(Collector<? super T#1,A,R#2>)
    A extends Object declared in method <R#2,A>collect(Collector<? super T#1,A,R#2>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2,K,U>toMap(Function<? super T#2,? extends K>,Function<? super T#2,? extends U>)
    K extends Object declared in method <T#2,K,U>toMap(Function<? super T#2,? extends K>,Function<? super T#2,? extends U>)
    U extends Object declared in method <T#2,K,U>toMap(Function<? super T#2,? extends K>,Function<? super T#2,? extends U...
```

Comment: Which compiler did you use? I tested `jdk1.8.0_05`, `jdk1.8.0_20`, `jdk1.8.0_40beta`, and `Eclipse Luna (4.4.0)`; none of them had any problems compiling the code.

Comment: @Holger I can reproduce the issue (you need to comment `.map(ZipEntry::name)` out) with jdk1.8.0_20 using javac.

Comment: @assylias: I see. Since 1.8u20 is the only one of my list having that problem, we have a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25414867/2711488) (or maybe related to [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25490581/2711488))?

Comment: yes, i was using u20 (the latest as of now). so it seems it might be fixed in future versions, good to hear.

Comment: I've seen this in u31 and can confirm it is gone in u60

Comment: I also got a similar error in a different context with `jdk1.8.0_25` and not with `jdk1.8.0_65`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be due to the fact that the stream type uses wild cards - not sure if this is expected behaviour. A workaround would be:

```
zipFile.stream().map(ZipEntry.class::cast) //or .map(z -> (ZipEntry) z)
```

Comment: aha I understand. Yes, also if I change to `((Stream<ZipEntry>)zipFile.stream())` instead of simply calling `stream()` it compiles. So, a limitation of the java8 type inference it seems.

Comment: Since I can’t reproduce the problem (see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157543/java8-collectors-tomap-limitation#comment41013050_26157543)) I suppose, this problem is not expected behavior…